# Google Cloud Vision - How to check logs that include original image uploaded or results of processed request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

We are trying to look into the details of Google Cloud Vision transactions. We are interested on the Cloud Vision requests where the returned processing is below satisfactory (e.g. empty JSON). **In general: we are interested in what input was received and what did GCV process with that?**

I had assumed this would be auto-logged?

It seems that the default logging solution does not provide much information about the value of the transaction other than the time or error type. (Is there a way to dig deeper into the log?)

**Is there a way to log (or somehow view the uploaded url of) the original image that the service received and/or the *results* of the processed request?**

Could you provide an example of how to retrieve the detected results and/or the input image, say, for "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"

Answer (score 1):

Can you be a bit more specific? Which specific Google Cloud Vision service are you trying to use (Image Classification, Object Detention)? Are you using the GCP console (i.e. UI), the API, ...? Which can of information do you want to get?

In any case, you can use [advanced logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries) to have a look at your Google Cloud Vision logs. For instance, you can use the following filter to see the error logs:

```
protoPayload.serviceName="vision.googleapis.com"

severity>=ERROR
```

Or remove the second line for getting all the logs related with Cloud Vision. You can then click on "Expand" to get all the information about the job.

Comment: Image Classification and Text/Handwriting. Using both console and API... of course? Is it possible for the logs to show more detailed information than that? Can it show what was detected? Or the original input image?

Comment: I guess I should update to say I'm not interested in knowing when the error occurs, but would like to triage what kind of inputs cause the errors. And generally I had assumed successes would be logged too so one can see what got processed.

Comment: Updated the question to clarify. I need to know more than that an error has occurred. I need to triage what kind of inputs (images) cause the errors, so it would be helpful to see processed results too. And generally I had assumed successes would be logged too so one can see what got processed.

Comment: Yes, successes are logged too. You just have to remove "severity>=ERROR" statement and you will all the logs. You can then click on "Expand" to see more information about the log and the specific error that you are getting when it is failing. So from that you can understand why a specific image failed.

Comment: I'm looking at logs and I'm still not sure how to have it retrieve the input data and output results. Could you provide an example of how to retrieve the detected results and/or the input image, say, for "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"? I mean, this type of result isn't useful to me, as I need to know both the input image and the processed response.

Comment: This is kind of useless to me since it does not tell me about the input image or processed result - for example, for DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION, wha textt did it process: `request: {
   @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.vision.v1.BatchAnnotateImagesRequest"    
   requests: [
    0: {
     features: [
      0: {
       maxResults: 20        
       type: "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"        
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  }`

Comment: I would say the logs are the only insight you can get into the processing. You cannot have information about the internal processing of the model since this would reveal parts of Google's code.

Comment: It's not regarding internal processing, but just what got sent and what got processed.

Comment: Currently, there is no way to access such information. It does not appear in the Stackdriver logs nor in the Cloud Audit - Data Access logs (https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/services, https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit). There is a feature request opened for this (https://issuetracker.google.com/151074729) but there is no ETA for this. You can subscribe to get any updates on the feature request (https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe).